# Submit a the value of a javascript variable along with a form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I submit a the value of a javascript variable along with a form submit? This is what I have so far:

```
var data = "abc";

$('form').submit(function(){
//add new hidden input field with value = data
});
```

Note: the html page will only have a single form.

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085091/submit-a-post-variable-with-javascript
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350917/send-post-variable-with-javascript

Comment: Further possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084749/how-do-i-submit-a-post-variable-with-javascript
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882211/pass-javascript-variable-to-php-post

I'm somewhat new but seeing the three answers already submitted I'm inclined to ask if this is the best way to [handle obvious duplicates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $('<input type="hidden" name="data" />').attr('value', data).appendTo(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $(this).append($('<input />').attr('name', 'data').attr('value', data));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = "abc";

$('form').submit(function(){
    $("form").append('<input type="hidden" name="data" value="' + data + '"');
});
```

Comment: Careful concatenating `data` into the input tag; if it contains a quote mark the resulting tag will be invalid. The `.attr()` or (in this particular case) `.val()` functions will do this more reliably.