# Adding Javascript variables into a MySql database on form submit

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding, google-places-api

I've got an application which makes use of the Google Maps Places Library. At the minute users can search for a start and end point using this library, click on one of the Autocomplete results and a route is drawn between these two point using the Directions Service.

I've come to the point where I need to add these values into a MySql database. I've already built the page which converts the contents of the database onto a new map (I used dummy content). The dummy content consists of a 'startlat', 'startlng', 'endlat' and 'endlng'. Basically what I need is to convert a Google Maps place into a separate latitude and longitude value so that I can pass it into my database.

I've read about Google's geocoding API, but I'm unsure as to whether I need to geocode if I'm already using the Places Library. Below is how I'm using the Places API.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  

    var rendererOptions = {
      draggable: true
    };
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    // Load options
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    // Try HTML5 geolocation
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }

  function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
    if (errorFlag) {
      var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
    } else {
      var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
    }

    var options = {
      map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(53.801158, -1.549158),
      content: content
    };

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
    map.setCenter(options.position);
  }

    // Load map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),mapOptions);

    // Popup window
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map
    });

    window.startLocation = null;
    window.endLoaction = null;

  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directionsPanel'));

    google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
  });

    // Autocomplete start
    var startInput = document.getElementById('start');
    var autocompleteStart = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(startInput);
    autocompleteStart.bindTo('bounds', map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(autocompleteStart, 'place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);
    startInput.className = '';
    var place = autocompleteStart.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      // Inform the user that the place was not found and return.
      startInput.className = 'notfound';
      return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
    }
    var image = {
      url: place.icon,
      size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
    };
    marker.setIcon(image);
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);

    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
      address = [
      (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
      (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
      (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
      ].join(' ');
    }

    window.startLocation = place;
    calcRoute();

    //infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
    //infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });


    // Autocomplete end
    var endInput = document.getElementById('end');
    var autocompleteEnd = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(endInput);
    autocompleteEnd.bindTo('bounds', map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(autocompleteEnd, 'place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);
    endInput.className = '';
    var place = autocompleteEnd.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      // Inform the user that the place was not found and return.
      endInput.className = 'notfound';
      return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
    }
    var image = {
      url: place.icon,
      size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
    };
    marker.setIcon(image);
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);

    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
      address = [
      (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
      (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
      (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
      ].join(' ');
    }

    window.endLocation = place;
    calcRoute();

  });

  function calcRoute() {

    var selectedMode = document.getElementById("mode").value;
      if(window.startLocation && window.endLocation) {
      var request = {
        origin: window.startLocation.formatted_address,
        destination: window.endLocation.formatted_address,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode[selectedMode]
      };
      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    $(".distance-value").html(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text)
                    $(".duration-value").html(response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text)
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
        });
      }
    }

    //End Maps Stuff

}); //End jQuery Document Ready
```

UPDATE - OK so I've figured out I don't need to Geocode, instead I can use this...

```
var startlocation = place.geometry.location;
    var startlat = location.lat();
    var startlng = location.lng();

var endlocation = place.geometry.location;
    var endlat = location.lat();
    var endlng = location.lng();
```

But how would I pass these values into the database on form submission?

Comment: You should update your question title to reflected your (new) question. Also, it's a bit open-ended. What have you tried?

Comment: I really don't have a clue where to start to be honest. On submit I take various elements from my form, but instead of posting the 'start' and 'end' inputs (which would be something along the lines of Manchester Railway Station or any other Google Maps Place that the user selects) I need to have the lat and long of the place instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submit a the value of a javascript variable along with a form submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380311/submit-a-the-value-of-a-javascript-variable-along-with-a-form-submit)